# Hide polygon shape after Click on HTML Imagemap

Tags: html, css

After clicking on an area tag inside an imagemap, the polygon shape of the area is getting displayed, even if I try to set set display: none for tag area.

But only in Chrome, Firefox doesn't display the shape. How can I hide this in Chrome?

```
      <map name="image-map">
          <area target="_self" alt="xy" title="xy" href="<?php echo get_home_url()?>xy" coords="xy" shape="poly">
      </map>
```

Comment: could you create a working example ... a fake image and your area/map set over it is fine. To check that you can reproduce your issue here with a minimum of code  ... could be outline ,but who knows what your style sheet is alike really. *(chrome was able to show areas years ago .. maybe it is still the case.)*

Comment: I had to find that example that still alows to style areas in chrome : https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/full/AJHmt . So what have you done with yours  to allow it to be seen in chrome .?